# Adding a train_test_split() to the K-Means algorithm code

Tags: python, algorithm, matplotlib, scikit-learn, k-means

I used K-Means and implemented train_test_split() which allowed me to get an accuracy score. I also found code that plots the centroids on matplotlib (as shown below). However, I can't figure out how to merge both of them so that I can implement a train_test_split() to get the accuracy_score() while at the same time being able to plot the centroids on a graph on the code shown.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn import metrics
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.array([3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 6, 6, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8, 9, 9, 8])
Y = np.array([5, 4, 6, 6, 5, 8, 6, 7, 6, 7, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3])

# Create new plot and data
data = np.array(list(zip(X, Y))).reshape(len(X), 2)

colors = ['b', 'g', 'c']
markers = ['o', 'v', 's']

# KMeans algorithm
model = KMeans(n_clusters=3).fit(data)

# Get Centroids
centers = np.array(model.cluster_centers_)

#Plot Graph
plt.title('K-Means Centroids')

for i, l in enumerate(model.labels_):
    plt.plot(X[i], Y[i], color=colors[l], marker=markers[l],ls='None')
    plt.xlim([0, 10])
    plt.ylim([0, 10])

plt.scatter(centers[:,0], centers[:,1], marker="x", color='r')
plt.show()
```

My question is: Is it possible to implement a train_test_split() on the code above?
My objective is: to get the accuracy_score() of the K-Means algorithm.

Comment: No, you can't do `train_test_split` and get the `accuracy_score`. It is because Kmean is an unsupervised learning algorithm, it is used for clustering, not classification. If you want to use `train_test_split` and get the `accuracy_score`, at least provide a target. Iris data maybe a good toy dataset to start with.